# Can't get Chart.js to run in a Vue.js component

Tags: chart.js, vue.js

So I am trying to display a nice chart using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) inside a Vue.js component... Should not be so complicated but I am hitting a wall there.

Here is my component code (syntax is based on [Vue.js webpack boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack))

```
<template>

  <canvas v-el:canvas style="width: 100%; height: 200px"></canvas>

</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js'

export default {
  compiled: function () {

    // fetch canvas DOM element
    let canvas = this.$els.canvas

    // init chart.js
    let chart = new Chart(canvas, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    })
    console.log(chart)

  }
}
</script>
```

I simplified the component as much as I could, and used data from the doc example (will bind real data using `props` later).

## So I keep getting this error in the console :

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

I looked it up, it seems that this has something to do with the variable passed to `getComputedStyle` used in Vue.js.

**My best guess** would be that `this.$els.canvas` does not return the right object. But if I output it in the console using `console.log` it seems right.

```
console.log(canvas)
// outputs <canvas style="width: 300px; height: 150px;"></canvas>
console.log(canvas.tagName)
// outputs CANVAS
console.log(canvas.style.height)
// outputs 200px
```

Hmmm this is actually weird and could be helpful : did you notice that I set the canvas `style.height` in the template, but if I do `console.log(canvas)` I see `height: 150px` but if `console.log(canvas.style.height)` 2 lines below, I get `200px` as an output ?!! WTF is going on ?.. Vue is messing with my head right now

**Link to jsFiddle for you to play with (check out the result in the console)**
https://jsfiddle.net/kartsims/g8s12yd2/3/#&togetherjs=CQrzT996AR

Comment: Your fiddle runs fine for me, just remove `display:none`.  What is the issue?

Comment: You are right... the problem was elsewhere. I'll leave an answer if anyone stumbles across the question. Thanks for looking into it anyway, your comment did help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out why and will let you know, just in case someone happens to be in the same position :

I couldn't get this to work **inside a vue component displayed by Vue Router**... I figured that it was because **I should have used `ready` hook instead of `compiled`**... At `compiled`, the DOM is not fully ready yet.